# PHP - Does session_unset unregister $_SESSION vars?

Tags: php, scripting, session, webserver

Does [session_unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) unregister all the $_SESSION vars, or do you have to manually clear each variable registered into the $_SESSION array with [unset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) ?

I'm confused about this because the PHP documentation says:

> Only use session_unset() for older deprecated code that does not use $_SESSION.
>
> If $_SESSION is used, use unset() to unregister a session variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it removes all sessions vars.

> session_unset — Free all session
>   variables

[www.php.net](http://www.php.net)

To remove all session vars, you can also use:

```
session_destroy();
```

Sometimes you might have problems even if using both session_unset and session_destroy. You have to clear $_SESSION array.

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
```