# is session_unset() the correct way to clear and reset PHP Sessions variables?

Tags: php

I am working on a session management function in PHP. I found a webpage that shows how to implement session timeouts (https://solutionfactor.net/blog/2014/02/08/implementing-session-timeout-with-php/)... I noticed that they use session_unset() and session_destroy() methods.

I am confused about the use of session_unset()

In looking at the PHP Manual (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php) there are notes that say:

> The session_unset() function frees all session variables currently registered.
>
> Note: If $_SESSION is used, use unset() to unregister a session variable, i.e. unset ($_SESSION['varname']);.
>
> Caution Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with unset($_SESSION) as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal.
>
> Note: Only use session_unset() for older deprecated code that does not use $_SESSION.

Here is what I have, based on the example on the page previously cited. ($sysTime will be the server's time passed to the function when called.

```php
//Define SYS_SES_TIMEOUT - How many seconds is a session valid for. 1800 seconds = 30 minutes
    define("SYS_SES_TIMEOUT", 1800);
    session_start();

    function fSessionMgmnt_isExpired($sysTime){
        if(isset($_SESSION['Expire_DT']) && ($sysTime - $_SESSION['Expire_DT']) > SYS_SES_TIMEOUT){
            session_unset(); session_destroy; session_start(); 
            //redirect to login page
        }else{//proceed to next check}
    }
```

My goal is that if the session is expired, the session is cleared out and the user is brought back to the login page to re-authenticate... where a new session would be created.

Based on the php manual, I am not sure if session_unset() is the correct method to use. Especially since session_destroy() says that it does not unset variables associated with the session and the session_unset() page notes about deprecated code.

Guidance is appreciated.

[Please note that while this has been flagged as a potential duplicate of [PHP - Does session_unset unregister $_SESSION vars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122659/php-does-session-unset-unregister-session-vars), I have to disagree, the suggested post asks what the function does, while my question is asking for the proper way to handle a scenario. ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Does session\_unset unregister $\_SESSION vars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122659/php-does-session-unset-unregister-session-vars)

Comment: Plese note there's a note in the manual: "Only use session_unset() for older deprecated code that does not use $_SESSION".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session_destroy() function:` It destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie.

> Note: If it’s desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie. This will destroy the session, and not just the session data.

`session_unset() function:` It deletes only the variables from session and session still exists. Only data is truncated.

You can visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303311/what-is-the-difference-between-session-unset-and-session-destroy-in-php) for more information and find out what you really need.

You can also see the examples describe [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/session_unset-vs-session_destroy-in-php/)

Comment: so if I use session_destroy() and then start a new session with session_start(), Would $_SESSION have the contents and values from the previous session remaining?

Comment: @psycoperl Nope, You won't have old session data after `session_destroy()`

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: you can forget that `session_unset()` exists. I don't know why it wasn't removed together with `session_register()`. It's just a remnant of the early session implementation in PHP/4.

Answer (score 0):

the `session_unset()` function is used to destroy a single session variable. but `session_destroy()` function destroys the whole php session. So in your case it is better to use `session_destroy()`.

Comment: This is not correct. `session_unset()` also works on all current session vars. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php